# How can I extract a prpt file to make changes to it without using Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I would like to edit the prpt file by making the changes to the .xml files within instead of editing it in pentaho Report designer.

I used winRAR and extracted the files, made the changes to the layout.xml and tried to "Add to Archive" by changing the extension to .prpt instead of .rar. This created the report fine but when I try to open this modified report in Pentaho report designer, it gives me "Unable to open the file as valid report definition".

I also tried doing the above without making any changes to any of the xml files but that did not work either.

Please can someone suggest any other way to do this. I would really appreciate any input on this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: This is definately an issue with winRAR and not PRPT's.  I've recently unzipped and re-zipped prpt's and it worked fine for me.  (using unix zip commands)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it in Unix and like you mentioned it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

prpt is just zip format. Be sure to indicate WinRAR to compress as zip, not as rar.

Additionally, also pay special attention to file content. Report files need to be in the root of the zip file and the datasources and manifest have to be in their respective directories.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. I tried to compress as zip and not as rar, the file does not open in Pentaho Report Designer. It gives me the following Exception: "Invalid key: No resource-loader registered for schema". Also the datasources and manifest files are in respective directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are simply compressing the folder in zip with extension prpt . Its a wrong approach jus compress the files in the folder not the folder  with prpt name and extension with prpt .

it should be zip not Rar